# How to prevent Kotlin from caching the state of ImageView inside an included XML layout by several fragments/activities

Tags: android, caching, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, synthetic

I have an XML layout named `layout_image` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/grumpy_cat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I include the XML in several activites/fragments

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/llytImage"
    layout="@layout/layout_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I set a color filter on `imageView`in Actitivty A by accessing it with kotlinx synthetic:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_image.view.*

llytImage.imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED)
```

It becomes red and I navigate to Activity B. Activity B also includes the same XML layout with the same id. However, `imageView` is still red in Activity B.

It seems Kotlin caches the state of `imageView` and use the same view aiming better performance.

However, I don't want it to cache `imageView`. I need the default state. I tried 2 ways to prevent Kotlin from caching it:

1. Using `@ContainerOptions(CacheImplementation.NO_CACHE)` annotation in activities which include the XML
2. Calling `imageView.clearFindViewByIdCache()` when navigating to Activity B

None of them worked for me.

If you know the true solution, I will be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you aren't manipulating the drawable rather than the image view?  There is a 0% chance that the image view is being cached between activities, Android doesn't work that way.  However the drawable can be, and you need to make a copy by calling mutate() on it before changing it, otherwise you effect all access to the base drawable.

Comment: @GabeSechan It caches the state when `Activity A -> Acitivty B`.
It does not cache the state when `Activity A -> MainActivity -> Activity B`
I will try `mutate()` method whether it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Views are specific to a single activity, they are not cached between them ever

Comment: Looked into the view caching annotation you mentioned. That's a flag to optimize lookups within an activity. It does not work between activities at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating the drawable rather than the image view by calling `mutate()` worked for me:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_image.view.*

val drawable = llytImage.imageView.drawable.mutate()
val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
drawable.colorFilter = colorFilter
```